# What ports does WeChat use to transfer data?

Tags: port

I want to block the messenging service, wechat, on my netgear router. Does anyone know the TCP/UDP ports that wechat uses to communicate?

WeChat is a Chinese messenging application developed by Tencent.
I did a google search but I could not find a website that actually lists the ports for wechat.

Comment: I don't know which/how they are being used, but on my Mac, the number of ports listed in Activity Monitor is 115,000! The next highest is 7,000 (Thunderbird). I'm very curious what this is about.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually possible to, in a general manner, find out what ports (relatively "well-behaved") applications use to communicate, so we don't necessarily need to know ahead of time what ports *WeChat specifically* uses. We can likely find that out for ourselves, and in the process, have a way to solve the problem *generally.*

Most applications that have some form of persistent monitoring (as instant messaging applications tend to) will need to connect to some sort of central server or messaging hub initially. If you are able to block that, the application should be unable to connect, and you have achieved your objective. Other types of applications that communicate over the Internet has the same need, but if it's only a very brief burst-type connection or even datagram transmission it can be difficult to catch, necessiting other techniques to identify the details (for example, network monitoring or firewall logging).

This works best for TCP, but certainly shouldn't be impossible to generalize to UDP.

The first step would be to take two dumps of the set of open connections: once without WeChat connected, and once with. By comparing them, we should be able to identify which ports are used by the application we are interested in. Such a connections list can be obtained through the `netstat` utility. The exact syntax varies, but on Linux (Windows is similar but probably not identical), you'd start with something like `netstat -an -A inet` which gives you a list of basically everything related to IPv4 without doing host name lookups. Take two and compare them. On Linux, you can do that in a single command with a little bit of shell magic:

```
$ diff -u0 <(netstat -an -A inet) <(sleep 10; netstat -an -A inet)
```

What this does is execute the two commands given, and show the difference between their outputs (the outputs are taken as the respective inputs to the `diff` tool; the `-u0` basically says do not print any context, because the context provides no useful information in our case). In our case, the commands are identical except the second one first calls `sleep 10` to give a ten-second delay. You'd adjust the delay time so that you have time to tell WeChat to connect; note that a longer delay will give more false positives in the diff output.

The output will tell you the source and destination IP address and port number for anything where the status has changed during the `sleep` period. Again, note that Windows' implementation of netstat may be somewhat different in details, but it allows you to do essentially the same thing. (You'll likely need to grab a diff tool from somewhere else, however. [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is fairly competent, free, and open source, although there certainly are others out there, both gratis and paid.)

That should *point you toward* what ports WeChat uses to communicate with its central servers. Do a reverse name lookup on the IP addresses if you are unsure what they are about. Note that some applications have fallback mechanisms (for example, they first try to communicate over a proprietary transport protocol, but if that fails they fall back to HTTP or HTTPS), in which case just blocking the default port(s) used won't be enough, but if that's the case, you'd need to look into other forms of blocking anyway.